# How do I install and configure the program cheat on Kali Linux from repo https://github.com/cheat/cheat?

Tags: git, installation

I am new to Kali Linux and I am trying to install the program `cheat` from the git repo https://github.com/cheat/cheat.

Most of the tutorials show how to install `cheat` by running `python setup.py` which seemed to work previously when the repo was hosted at https://github.com/chrisallenlane/cheat. However, this file is no longer present in current repo.

I have cloned the new git repo, but I do not know how to install the program from new repo.

Comment: The README says to download from the [release page](https://github.com/cheat/cheat/releases)

Comment: have downloaded the files from release page. its a gz file. extracted the files, but dont know where to go from there. how to install the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the binary from the [release page](https://github.com/cheat/cheat/releases).

Open a terminal in the download folder, to decompress the `.gz` file type:

```
gzip -d <downloaded_file.gz>
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x <downloaded_file> # No gzip extension this time
```

Now you can run it:

```
./<downloaded_file>
```

Optionally, copy it to somewhere in your PATH:

```
cp <downloaded_file> /usr/local/bin/cheat
```

Now you can run it by simply typing `cheat`

Here is a full example with amd64:

```
cd ~/Downloads
gzip -d cheat-linux-amd64.gz
chmod +x cheat-linux-amd64
sudo cp ./cheat-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/cheat

# Run with:
cheat
```

Comment: Thanks Omer. Great, finally managed to get it working. Apart from following the above steps had to set the default editor and run these commands in the terminal.

Comment: cheat --init > ~/.config/cheat/conf.yml
export CHEAT_CONFIG_PATH="~/config/cheat/conf.yml"
export EDITOR="/usr/bin/nano"